# tensorflow object detection trained model not working

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection

I trained my dataset for tensorflow object detection using both ssd and faster r-cnn model.There were 220 train and 30 test images in my dataset.
I trained the model for 200k steps and got loss under 1.But when i tested my trained model on video it was detecting and labelling almost everything in the video.
Can anyone tell me why is that happening?
Thank you

Comment: please add the number of classes and the input size of the image

Comment: This must be an overfitting problem.

Comment: @janu777 number of classes is one and input size is 300*300

Comment: In your model config file, did you change 'score_threshold' to, say, 0.3?

Answer (score 0):

The number of classes you are using is just one and you trained your model with images belonging to the same class and tested it for the same.

So the problem is the model is skewed(predicts the same for all images)
No matter whatever image you test it on, you will get the same output.

Solution:

Train you model with an nearly equal number of negative images.

Ex:220 images containing the object to be identified(label them as 1) and another nearly 220 images not containing the object(label them as 0)

Use F1 score to check your accuracy because it will help you understand if the dataset is skewed or not.

Check [this](http://blog.exsilio.com/all/accuracy-precision-recall-f1-score-interpretation-of-performance-measures/) to learn about different kinds of accuracy measures.
Take [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3FW7Lu3i5JvHM8ljYj-zLfQRF3EO8sYv) course to learn more about CNNs.

Comment: Thanks .I will retrain and post back in couple of days.

Comment: Still not working .on images it works to some extent  but on videos it detects everything wrong or detect nothing.i trained my  model with 4 classes and 500k steps (loss 0.98).please suggest me what i can do.my motive is to detect people based on specific clothing(e.g. staff members).

Comment: Name all 4 of your classes and how many training samples you have in each one of them

Comment: staff,macncheese,racoon and dog.220 each.staff class is my own data rest all are from internet

Comment: You need more data. And first try training your model with some of the basic classes like dogs/cats, and see if it works. https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition. In there you will find people discussing and uploading good working kernels. So you will get a good idea of what's going wrong

Comment: i have same problem, i read we don't have to train negative picture, because in picture all areas without boxes is a negative test, record negative test only if you want to distinguish between a picture labelised or not labelised (there is detected object or not)

i train several time with severa models always same problem. it does'nt work

Comment: test with pretrained model work, but we want our trained model